# Python для управления android телефоном

Tags: python, android, администрирование, vpn

Идея такая: у меня есть сервера ВПН. Ip , пароль и прочее есть. Нужна библиотека которая позволить автоматизировать подключение к серверу. Не конкретно с ВПН , а вообще с настройками андроид ,настройками подключения и прочим

Comment: можете попробовать покопать в сторону `ADB (Android Debug Bridge)`

Comment: есть вроде даже библиотека для управления через ADB, [тык](https://pypi.org/project/adb-shell/)